# Why doesn't mysql show up under gem list after installing successfully?

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

Here's the deal:
$ gem -v

```
1.3.7
```

$ gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/harriett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/harriett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/harriett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/harriett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial
     - /Users/harriett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1  
1 gem installed
```

$ gem list mysql

```
* LOCAL GEMS *
```

Why doesn't it show up?
Naturally, when I require "mysql" in a ruby program I get:

```
`require': no such file to load -- mysql (LoadError)
```

Comment: do this in terminal `gem list'

Comment: gem list gives me a list of all my installed gems, of which 'mysql' is not found

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using and what OS?

Comment: And what does `gem env` show?

Comment: Do the answers here help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925689/archflags-not-taking-command-mysql-64-bit-ruby-gem-installation-issues-on-snow-l/3974716#3974716

Comment: This question should help you (seems its the same problem as yours) : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1206143/382818

Comment: If you `require 'rubygems'` before the `require 'mysql'`, does that work?

Comment: require 'rubygems' didn't work... The question you linked to suggests, "The ruby mysql gem doesn't like the 64-bit version on Leopard. If you can, downgrade."  But I don't understand what 64-bit version is causing the problem (mysql, ruby?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ruby install is being managed by RVM. See "[DO NOT use sudo...](https://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems)" on the RVM site.

Try installing it *without* `sudo` and it should show up in your gemlist.

Comment: I had to learn it the same way. Old habits die hard you know.

Comment: Can you explain what this link was to?  Seems to be broken atm

Comment: It was to a section in the site that said "DO NOT use sudo". Why is too long to be explained here in depth, but basically sudo changes the effective user who won't have the same paths set up, causing any actions to occur outside the Ruby managed by RVM or rbenv, which is NOT what you want to do. BTW, I fixed the link.